# Purescript-react and inserting html symbols

Tags: purescript

How to insert html symbols in purescript-react? The following code writes into the modal a string "&times:" that works like a closing button. The equivalent html-example shows x-character (times-).

```
import React.DOM as D
import React.DOM.Props as P

[ D.button [P._type "button"
           , P.className "close"
           , P._data {dismiss: "modal"}
           ]
           [ D.text "&times;" ]
```

Probably D.text should be something else but couldn't find a proper function to call. Or is there another totally different and intended way to do this?

Comment: Use a valid escape code instead of the HTML escape, or the actual character "×".

Comment: Thanks, do you mean something like [ D.text $ S.fromCharArray [C.fromCharCode 0x00d7] ] using UTF-16 codes? Now I can do this and turn other html escapes to utf when needed. (My first thougth was that there is and thus to find a function like "htmlEncode" or "htmlEscape" or htmlSymbol" etc.)

Comment: Having the same issue trying to insert HTML symbols into React; it would be nice to see an official answer.